# Finding a Taylor Series Representation: $f(x)= \frac{x}{(1+4x^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find Taylor series representations for the following function. For precisely what values of $x$ is the series representation valid?

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+4x^2)^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume you are familiar with the basic geometric series/function relation

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Typically, when you are asked to find a Taylor series representation for a function that looks at all similar to the above, you are expected to manipulate the given function and force it into this form.

The four typical manipulations that you may be expected to perform are:

> 1. Substitution for $x$

For example, the following (where we substitute $-3x^2$ for $x$) is valid
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-3x^2)^n}=\frac{1}{1-(-3x^2)}=\frac{1}{1+3x^2}$$

This is how you accommodate a plus sign in the denominator

> 2. Factoring / multiplying

$$\frac{4x^2}{1-x}=4x^2\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=4x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}$$

> 3. Integration

The basic thought behind this manipulation is that term by term integration of a power series is mathematically valid. So if you can identify that the function in question is the integral of a function whose power series is known, you can integrate each term of the sum as below. (A constant of integration is still required.
$$\ln(1-x) = \int{\frac{-1}{1-x}dx}= -\int{\frac{1}{1-x}dx}=\int{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}dx}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\int{x^n}dx} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}} + C$$

> 4. Differentiation

This is the same as manipulation 3 but used derivatives instead of integrals.

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{nx^{n-1}}$$

Note that the sum after taking the derivative begins at 1 (rather than 0).

Now after that long-winded explanation, we can manipulate the equation and actually solve the problem. I'll outline the steps

> 1. Rewrite the function as a derivative (I'm not going to show the steps but if you can't visualize it from experience, you can actually take the integral)

$$\frac{x}{(1+4x^2)^2}=\frac{-1}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1+4x^2}\right)$$

> 2. Now rewrite to allow for substitution.

$$\frac{-1}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1+4x^2}\right)=\frac{-1}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-(-4x^2)}\right)$$

> 3. Replace the rational function with the power series in line 1 of this long answer

$$\frac{-1}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-(-4x^2)}\right)=\frac{-1}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-4x^2)^n}\right)=\frac{-1}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-4)^n(x^{2n})}\right)$$

> 4. Take the derivative term by term

$$\frac{-1}{8}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-4)^n(x^{2n})}\right)=\frac{-1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-4)^n(2n)(x^{2n-1})}$$

And that is your answer.

The values of $x$ for which the Taylor series is valid can be found using the ratio test (I'm too tired to write the actual steps but here are the results)

Series converges when $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$

Finally, it is necessary to test the boundaries of the interval of convergence (-0.5 and .5) because the ratio test is inconclusive for these points.

It turns out, because the ratio simplifies to 1 in both cases, the deries diverges at both boundaries.  So the final interval of convergence is

$$\frac{-1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

*Solution 1*.

*Hint*. Observe that

> $$
> -\frac1{16}\left(\frac{1}{1-2 i x}+\frac{1}{1+2 i x}\right)'=\frac{x}{(1+4x^2)^2}.
> $$

Can you take it from here?

*Solution 2*.

*Hint*. Observe that, by differentiating a standard geometric series evaluation, one gets

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty nX^n=\frac{X}{(1-X)^2},\quad |X|<1.
> $$

Put $X:=-4x^2$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-4)^nx^{2n}=\frac{-4x^2}{(1+4x^2)^2}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29),
$$ \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+1}{1}z^n =\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1) z^n$$
where the radius of convergence at $z=0$ is $1$ (since $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n+2}{n+1}=1$ or just because one is the distance from the closest singularity, namely the double pole at $z=1$). By replacing $z$ with $-4x^2$ we get:

> $$ \frac{x}{(1+4x^2)^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n 4^n (n+1)\,x^{2n+1}$$

where the radius of convergence at $x=0$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.